# Returning unique valued entities with their count?

Tags: mysql, count

Suppose I have a MySQL table

```
id (primary key), tag,    entity id
1,                food,   77
2,                shop,   98
3,                food,   32
...
```

I'd like to return the total counts of the same tag sorted in decreasing number of entries.  Aka,

```
tag,     count
food,    2
shop,    1
...
```

How would I go about writing an efficient query for this?  Would it be better to create a separate counter table to increase efficiency for queries like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*) `count`
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY tag
 ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Output:

```
|  TAG | COUNT |
|------|-------|
| food |     2 |
| shop |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6e81/3)** demo

Comment: It does work!  I'm using Hibernate HQL to write this, and I was wondering how would one go about reading this into an object?  Usually the type that I return is a predefined entity that's a table.  Do I need to cast the return result type in this case?

Comment: @Luke I'm glad it works :). Unfortunately I'm not an expert in  Hibernate HQL. So I guess another question is in order. Meanwhile if the answer solved the problem you stated in your original question please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was at 0. It worked great, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL Docs, the most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index.

I guess that you query will something like that:

```
Select tag, count(*) from your_table group by tag order by 2 desc;
```

So, You should index the 'tag' column to improve the query.